# How to select row with the highest values in Laravel

Tags: laravel-4

I am trying to select 3 rows that have the 3 highest values in Laravel. How can I do this?

```
$data = DB::table('election')->select('election_id')->take(3)->max('votes');
```

This is not working

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by using the following code;

```
$data =  DB::table('election')
                ->select('election_id', DB::raw("(select max('votes') from election)"))
                ->take(3)->get();
```